# Localhost htaccess not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got the following .htaccess which is not working:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /coffee_shop/

# For sales:
RewriteRule ^shop/sales/?$ sales.php

# For the primary categories:
RewriteRule ^shop/(coffee|goodies)/?$ /shop.php?type=$1

# For specific products:
RewriteRule ^browse/(coffee|goodies)/([A-Za-z\+\-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ browse.php??type=$1&category=$2&id=$3

# For shop:
RewriteRule ^shop/([A-Za-z\+]+)/?$ shop.php?type=$1

</IfModule>
```

When I access http://localhost/coffee_shop/html/shop/goodies is supposed to be translated to http://localhost/coffee_shop/html/shop?type=goodies but that's not the case. I'm getting a 404 Object Not Found error so the file is getting read (I put some garbage code in it and resulted in a 500 error).

1. The folder structure is:

   - htdocs/
      -project1/
      -project2/
      -coffee_shop/

I don't want to move the .htaccess to the root because I might use a different .htaccess in some other project.

2. Yes, AllowOverride is set to All in httpd.conf
3. Tried adding to httpd.conf `<Directory /Applications/XAAM/htdocs/coffee_shop>AllowOverride All</Directory>` but it didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: The urls you list after the htaccess rules include html in the path but these are not referenced in the rewrite rules

Answer (score 2):

To me it looked like you were missing the "html" part to your rewrite rules - it was referenced in the urls but not the rule - hence 404

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /coffee_shop/

    # For sales:
    RewriteRule ^html/shop/sales/?$ sales.php

    # For the primary categories:
    RewriteRule ^html/shop/(coffee|goodies)(/?)$ shop.php?type=$1

    # For specific products:
    RewriteRule ^html/browse/(coffee|goodies)/([0-9]+)(/?)$ browse.php?type=$1&id=$2

    # For shop:
    RewriteRule ^html/shop/([A-Za-z\+]+)(/?)$ shop.php?type=$1

</IfModule>


http://localhost/coffee_shop/html/shop?type=goodies can be accessed via  http://localhost/coffee_shop/html/shop/goodies
```

Comment: I added the html as you mentioned in your answer but it didn't work. And yes, I did restart apache ;)

Comment: I have just set up a new directory on dev server called coffee_shop and created the three pages you have here. The rules I posted work but I notice now that there is an error with one of your original rules - namely the one that points to browse.php - it should be something akin to browse.php?type=$1&id=$2 as there are 2 placeholders in the rewrite rule and imcorrectly referenced variables t the end - and missing one

Comment: The browse part is my mistake, I copied directly from the terminal whatever was on the screen, I forgot to move the cursor to the right to copy the extra part in the browse line. Still, I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I made the changes you suggested but I keep getting the 400 error